# Getting wrong results when mapping from json to object

Tags: java, gson

I am writing a java application using Spring and other frameworks. I am trying to use GSON to get data from string to custom objects. In my code, I use `GSON` to map a string to custom object. This is how I do it:

```
gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), Hello.class)
```

In my `Hello.java`, I have:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Hello {

    @JsonProperty("test1")
    List<Test1> test1;

    @JsonProperty("test2")
    List<Test2> test2;

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Test1 {

    @JsonProperty("a")
    private String a;

    @JsonProperty("b")
    private String b;

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Test2 {

    @JsonProperty("x")
    private Test3 test3;

    @JsonProperty("y")
    private String y;

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Test3 {

    @JsonProperty("l")
    private String l;

    @JsonProperty("m")
    private String m;

}
```

And my JSON looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    "test1": [
        {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "b"
        }
    ],
    "test2": [
        {
            "x": {
                "l": "l",
                "m": "m"
            },
            "y": "y"
        }
    ]
}
```

But only the test1 is loaded fine with all values correctly by the Gson whereas test2 is completely null. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 then test

Comment: Why do you use `Jackson` annotation and `Gson` library? Try to use `ObjectMapper` from `Jackson` library to read `JSON` payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), Hello.class);
```

use

```
String json = new String(response.body().bytes());
gson.fromJson(json , Hello.class)
```

And also, check your `json` string there might be invalid characters might be comes from not well web service design for example : 2 double quote start and end of json string.

`\"{\"message\":\"hello\"}\"` <= this is wrong

**correct is**

`{\"message\":\"hello\"}` or `{"message":"hello"}`

And also use `@SerializedName` instead of `@JsonProperty`

And finally check json keys which are **case sensitive** i mean `M` is not equal to `m`

Comment: This maybe a good solution but I managed to get it work using Jackson